# JavaFX ReadFile counter + another counter task?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, task, counter

i have a UI whit 2 labels.

First Label: All Lines
Second Label: Lines ends with xxx

My Programm Read a File and in a Task he Read all Lines:

```
public class ReadFileTask extends Task<Void> {

@Override
protected Void call() throws Exception {

    File file = new File("comments.txt"); //TODO

    long lines = Files.lines(file.toPath()).count();
    long line = 0;
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    while ((reader.readLine()) != null) {
        line++;
        updateMessage("" + line);

    }
    return null;
}}
```

Now i have the First label.

For the 2nd Label i try this:

```
public class ReadFileTask extends Task<Void> {
        static int xxxLines = 0;
@Override
protected Void call() throws Exception {

    File file = new File("comments.txt"); //TODO

    long lines = Files.lines(file.toPath()).count();
    long line = 0;
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    while ((reader.readLine()) != null) {
        line++;
        updateMessage("" + line);

                if (reader.readLine().endsWith("xxx")) {  
          xxxLines++;


                }          
    }
    return null;
}}
```

the Button is:

```
    public void Datei(ActionEvent event) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    ReadFileTask task = new ReadFileTask();
    daten.textProperty().bind(task.messageProperty());
    new Thread(task).start();
    Platform.runLater(()->xxx.setText("" + ReadFileTask.xxxLines));

}
```

Comment: There are several ways to do this. Read through the [documentation for `Task`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) which has plenty of examples. Try one of the approaches after reading that, and edit your question with more specifics if you still have trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Platform.runLater()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-) for your second Label. But beware: Do not flood the GUI Thread with these updates:

```
Platform.runLater(()->xxxLabel.setText("" + xxxLines));
```

Comment: i have try runLater, but the problem is, the gui whit the label is in Controller.class, the task is in ReadFileTask.class, when i try this then i get local variables refenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final, i know i must read more the documentation but me english is so bad, i try to read tuturials in german from google but it is hard, whitout help i never learn this, the most time i learn whit example codes but sometimes for problems like this i do not find examples

Comment: I do not really get the problem? Are you new to Java? You can pass the Label along with methods and/or constructor arguments..

Comment: my Controller whit the start button is now your code insite, in the controller is static int xxxLines = 0; and if (reader.readLine().endsWith("xxx")) { xxxLines++; } .. when i start, its working, he read the 0 from the static int.. when i put 1 insite then the gui show me a 1, but it is not refresh :/

Comment: when i use static Label web =  new Label(); in the controller ( ui class ) then i get no exception but i get no value... if i use public static Label web; then i get the first value what is set in the ReadFileTask but no refresh, when i put the Platform.runLater(.... from the Controller ( ui Button ) in the ReadFileTask class then i get exception i have no idea i work so long time for this sh...

Comment: I said use the `Platform.runLater(...` **inside**  your Task. Or more specific: Inside your `Task`s `call()` method, whenever you want to update a Label.

Comment: i try this... Task: Platform.runLater(()->Controller.xxxLabel.setText("" + xxxLines));  and in Controller: public static Label web; result: Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException   at email.ReadFileTask.lambda$call$0(ReadFileTask.java:48) Line = Platform.runLater(()->Controller.xxxLabel.setText("" + xxxLines));  problem: Controller.xxxLabel < null

Comment: This means that you never initialized the Label. Again: Java basics.. Another reminder: StackOverflow is not here for code review, there is a special site for that.

Comment: i thing the problem is FXML file... when i make static Label web = new Label(); then the label do not refresh... can u not help me to fix this? :/

Comment: FXML will not inject static fields. You will have to find another way around this.

Comment: Thanks, my way: filewriter counter, next loop, filereader + filewriter to get the numbers.. not the right way but idk other way